# Sending an object through the internet and invoking it's method

Tags: java, object

I've got a java web server and I made it so that the server will respond to a certain a http* request by sending back a java object that contains a "execute" method.

I'd like to be able to execute a remote object's method.

- I can't use reflection because I don't send the class, thinking about making a local class that has the same method + package-name so i can try to object.getClass()
- I won't like to put the entire block of code in the toString() from the object that I will send. (Override)
- I can't cast to an interface.

I'm also thinking about making a .jar library that has the definition for the class file that will be created on the server and accessed on the client, how can this work?

I couldn't find another question regarding this, so I will leave this here.

EDIT:

- I'm using URLConnection to communicate with a servlet, the servlet makes an instance of the object on the server then it will send it to the client using ObjectOutputStream, as well as ObjectInputStream on the client for it to get it.
- Looking for some alternatives to RMI, if none, I will lookup some RMI tutorials.
- Regarding about my choice to not use RMI in the first place: maybe I don't want every time to make a connection between client-server , maybe I want to deserialize objects and check/invoke it's methods.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/ or some other RMI is probably what you're looking for. I'll write a propper answer when I have time if no one else does.

Comment: "Server will respond to html request" is browser the client ? If so, browser can not understand Java serialized object bytes.  What is your requirement ? Java RMI helps you with what you need between 2 Java applications but not between browser and web server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to "send" serialized objects from one java virtual machine (java process) to another, you need to have the .class files already present at both ends. If you decide to continue with your current approach, you would need the following:

- Your client must be Java, or be able to run Java, and have the .class files that correspond to the objects that it is receiving locally available, or must download them from the server before accessing them.
- You must somehow wrap serialized object streams within HTTP. HTTP is a protocol for requesting and sending web pages. It is incompatible with Java's serialization protocol (it contains extra headers, for example), and you would need to wrap Java serialization inside HTTP payloads for things to work as you seem to expect.
- When you send serialized objects, you are actually sending "object graphs" (the object and all objects accessible by navigating its fields). This can end up being inefficient. Serialization may not be the best answer for you for this reason.

It is far easier to use other mechanisms:

- If you avoid HTTP, you avoid the need for extra wrappers. Writing a simple server that, when connected to, receives and sends serialized objects is much easier and efficient than writing a wrapper for HTTP within a traditional Java webapp (Java app servers tend to be resource-hungry).
- Consider using [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) or other Java serialization/networking libraries - they come with built-in servers, and allow very fine-grained control over what is being sent.
- Java has in-built support for RMI ("Remote Method Invocation"). This seems to be what you are actually trying to achieve. You no longer need to be aware that objects are local or remote - they appear to work the same, and all required networking and serialization is done behind the scenes. Read [all about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/).

Comment: I made it work by having the same classes on both ends, the client will download them.